# Orbit a planet partially around a sun

Tags: modeling, transforms

New file.  Two objects:

1. Sun is centered at cursor over XY intersection.
2. Planet orbiting that sun is displaced a few units away along the Y axis.

Task:
Keep sun centered in place over cursor in the center of the XY intersection.  But orbit the planet 120° toward the other side of the sun.

Comment: hello, could you please show a drawing of what you want to do?

Comment: Add an Empty (plain axes) at the center of the XY intersection and parent the Planet to the Empty. Then, rotate the empty to make the planet "orbit".

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.